# How do analyse if a difference between two scores of Cramer's V is significant?

Tags: correlation, cramers-v

Previous research shows that there is a correlation between two variables. I am researching whether this is true in different groups. It seems like there is:

Group 1: X2 (2) = 44.822, p < .001, Cramer’s V = .763. N = 77
Group 2: X2 (2) = 30.147, p < .001, Cramer’s V = .582. N = 89

I am wondering whether the difference between these scores is significant. It seems like the correlation is stronger in group 1? How do I calculate this?

Note that these are categorical variables. What should be used instead of a T-test?

(I am using SPSS - no formal training in statistics, so excuses there)

Comment: +1 for thinking to ask this important question in your research

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but a theory-based answer would require the sampling distribution of Cramer's V, and then calculating the difference between two variables with that distribution. I do know that Cramer's V is based on the chi-square statistic, so this could be a tractable computation

Comment: Have you checked whether the pattern of the results is the same?

Comment: The pattern is roughly the same, but suggests that the influence of the variable in group 2 is weaker.

in percentages, where the percentage reflects the positive result within each category:
group 1: 87/26/0
Group 2: 67/11/11

Comment: To clarify: we are talking about a 2x3 table.
Or, if we have two groups, a 2x2x3 table.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613376/test-to-compare-multiple-contingency-tables