# Test to compare multiple contingency tables

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, contingency-tables, log-linear

I have three contingency tables with the variables month and region that contain the frequency of the sighting of a particular bird. Additionally, the tables differ only by counting frequencies from different years.

I am looking for a way to see if there is a significant change in the frequencies between the tables.

A Chi-squared test seems almost plausible, but there are no expected values and I don't need to see a relationship between the two variables, but rather how the frequencies change over time across the three tables.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: (1) "I have three contingency tables with the variables month and region that contain the frequency of the sighting of a particular bird. Additionally, each table covers a different time period." does it mean that you have a contingency table for each time period? (2) "A Chi-squared test almost seems plausible, but there are no expected values and I don't need to see a relationship between the two variables, but rather between the three tables." what do you mean by a relationship between the three tables?

Comment: are you only interested in the pattern of cell frequencies across time? In addition, what is the relation between the three tables? Are the counts repeated? perhaps you have areas observed over different time periods? Please explain and add any relevant information directly to your post.

Comment: Edits made- but yes the each of the three tables are from different years, so I am looking for a way to analyze how the frequencies change across the three tables.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this problem by means of a Poisson log-linear model. Without entering into technical details, for which you can check Agresti's book Categorical Data Analysis, Wiley, chap. 8, the model I'd use, or at least a *starting point*(*), is a Poisson regression. In this model, the statistical unit is the cell of each contingency table and the idea is to model the expected counts as a function of the three available covariates: `month`, `region` and `time`. For instance, if your tables are, say $12 \times 10$, across all the 3 time periods, then you'll have $12*10*3=360$ observations.

The model in `R` should look something like this

```
my_glm <- glm(counts ~ month*region + time, data= mydata, family = poisson())
anova(my_glm)
```

Through the `anova` function you check if there is a significant `time` effect. All the other coefficients are there for flexibility reasons are essentially irrelevant to your aim.

*Starting point*(*) It may turn out that after some checks the Poisson assumption is not adequate. If that's the case, you could consider fitting an over-dispersed Poisson model (see, e.g. Breslow, N.E. 1984, Extra-Poisson variation in log-linear models, *Applied Statistics*, **33**, 38–44.) an implementation of which can be found in the `glm.poisson.disp` function of the `R` package `dispmod`.